# check file existence from root

Tags: php, file-exists, document-root

I tried the following code to check existence of file in root.

```
if($res['profile_picture']!="" && file_exists("images/".$res['users_id']."/thumnails/".$res['profile_picture'])){
    $photo_p="images/".$res['users_id']."/thumnails/".$res['profile_picture'];
}
```

It works only on root directory not sub directory.

I'm not sure whether function file_exist checks for both absolute and relative paths so I tried adding ROOT and `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. But still it didn't worked out.

Any Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For code portability I suggest you always use absolute paths in functions like `file_exists()`, otherwise you may wind up breaking your head when including multiple files in different directories and/or running in CLI mode.

`ROOT` constant may be undefined in your code. Also, `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` in some circumstances cannot be relied on, i.e. when you use `vhost_alias` apache module.

Generally,

```
file_exists("{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/images/{$res['users_id']}/thumnails/{$res['profile_picture']}")
```

should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The function file_exists() checks exactly the path you give to it. There is no fancy magic in there.

Hand it an absolute path and it will check that path. Hand it a relative path and it will check from the current working directory. You might want to think about what actually is your working directory.